# SQLite LazyLoadingEnabled not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I am using SQLite and I have `LazyLoadingEnabled = true` (this is supposed to be the default but I still turned in on by setting it to `true`). My navigation properties are virtual. However, SQLite loads everything. I have plenty of experience with EF so I am well aware of lazy loading.

There is not much online about EF to SQLite lazy loading, everything is about EF to SQL Server lazy loading.

Do I need to do anything else for SQLite? Or is this a bug?

Here is the code in case it helps:

```
this.context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```